# Minecraft 1.13 Filled Map Glitch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on an adventure map and discovered this bug that produces ghost filled maps. What I did was:

1. Have a Repeat Command Block set to "Always Active" and run /clear @a filled_map
2. Hold 2 or more blank maps
3. Right click 1 blank map and a ghost filled map pops up.

[image: Ghost Filled Map]

As you can see, Minecraft thinks that I only have blank maps and not the ghost filled map. The ghost filled map disappears whenever I re-log, but I can't ask the players who play my map to re log every single time they run into this glitch. So I was wondering if there are any methods that I could work my way around this problem?

Comment: Why do you do all of this at all?

Comment: because I'm making a multiplayer map where players have active skill items and those items are "blank maps," but in order to know whether one has activated their skill, I make commands to detect whether a filled map exists and clear them, that's why

Comment: Oh, so this is a click detection? There are easier ways to do that, just google "minecraft left click detection" or "minecraft right click detection".

Comment: couldn't you simply set up a scoreboard thing with the ``usedItem`` stat, then clear everyone of that item? i feel like that could be a possibility, but you would possibly run into the same clear bug.

Comment: the situation is the "ghost map" is produced when you have a repeat block running clear item command, and the ghost item can't be detected by minecraft using the "/data" command or player's nbt tags. I just went with Nik3141's solution. Give the players when their item was just cleared a gray stained glass pane, clear the pane immediately. This solves the ghost item problem, making minecraft update a player's inventory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was testing this and accidentally picked up a stone button, which then took the place of the ghost map. You can give the player with the ghost map a specially named/enchanted item (so it cannot be acquired in any other way) and then clear it from their inventory, which will also clear the ghost map from their inventory. If you used a datapack you could set up a tick function which clears the map and has a scoreboard to store the success of the clearing map command, and if that scoreboard shows that a map was cleared you give and clear the special item and then reset the scoreboard.